# What does exactly AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP do in android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am trying to learn AlarmManager in android.I came across the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP) to understand the use of AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP .But when i used this in my app and when the app ran,i clicked the back button thinking that alarm manager will again call the activity after the alarm interval time set here

```
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+10*1000, alarmIntent);
```

But nothing happens.Please somenone explain the meaning of `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,0);
        Log.d("asd","initialized alarmintent");
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+10*1000, alarmIntent);

                        Log.d("asd", "alarm set");
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intent_layout);
        Log.d("asd","writing textview");
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText("called");
    }
}
```

Comment: "But nothing happens" -- perhaps there is an issue with the strangely-named `AlarmReceiver`, such as it not being registered in the manifest. Check LogCat for any messages.

Comment: @CommonsWare,i have made the entry for AlarmReceiver in manifest file.It is the class i am calling when the alarm is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` as opposed to `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`. Here is an example of how I was using AlarmManager in a recent app:

MainActivity.class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,  0, intent, 0);

    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // Cancel any existing service(s)
    mAlarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    // Start service
    long alarmTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000L; // 10 seconds from now
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mAlarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public AlarmReceiver() { }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "AlarmService Triggered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Service triggered");
    }
}
```

it seems like your AlarmReceiver class was extending `AppCompatActivity` which won't work - you need to extend `Broadcast Receiver` as I have done. Then, within the `onReceive()` function in AlarmReceiver, you need to navigate to your desired Activity, like this:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
context.startActivity(newIntent);
```

Try these changes and see if they work!

Comment: ,Can u explain the use of AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP ?

Comment: @a874 see a description here - http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set - As the guide says, RTC is more for actual "alarms" whereas ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP is more for scheduling tasks. That said, I still prefer RTC in my own implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine.
Make sure you have declared your AlarmReceiver activity in the manifest, something like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm_receiver"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```